# Getting Error NoReverseMatch at / |

Tags: python, django

Error - NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'Detail_function' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['function\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']

MY CODE
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.HomeFunction, name= 'home_function'),

    path('function/<int:pk>/',views.DetailFunction, 
name='Detail_function'),
]
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def HomeFunction(request):
    form = Profile.objects.all()
    context ={'form':form}
    return render (request,'home_function.html',context)

def DetailFunction(request,pk):
    form=get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)
    return render(request,'detail_function.html',{'form':form})
```

templates
home_function.html

```
    {% for i in form %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">{{i.name}},{{i.gender}}</a> </li>

    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

detail_function.html

```
<ul><li>{{form.name}}  |  {{form.gender}}</li></ul>
```

> **BUt when im adding {% url 'Detail_Function' object.pk %} in home_function.html like below**

```
{% for i in form %}
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'Detail_function' object.pk %}">{{i.name}}, 
   {{i.gender}}</a> </li>

</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

its throwing NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'Detail_function' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['function\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']

showing error at `<a href="{% url 'Detail_function' object.pk %}">`

Please be guiding me,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object is not instance of your form. to generate url, you should use i

```
<a href="{% url 'Detail_function' i.pk %}">
```

Comment: thanks,it solved my problem, actually my tutor taught me wrong,he said by default django generic view create object form and we can access it by name object or post! lolz

Comment: @Chidananda, you can learn from django official site. They have explained everything in details.

Comment: sir, is there any other site or book whom I can read... Official Django site is bit hard for me.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak, you can try this book two scoops of django